# More then 1 command in the Java 8 foreach function

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Is it possible to use more than one command in the Map.foreach function that got introduced with Java 8?

So instead:

```
map.forEach((k, v) -> 
System.out.println(k + "=" + v));
```

I want to do something like:

```
map.forEach((k, v) -> 
System.out.println(k)), v.forEach(t->System.out.print(t.getDescription()));
```

Lets pretend that k are Strings and v are Sets.

Comment: The answer is the same for whenever you want to combine multiple statements into a block of code -- use curly braces: `map.forEach((k, v) -> {...}`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [lambda syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#syntax) allows two kinds of definitions for the body:

- a single, value-returning, expression, eg: `x -> x*2`
- multiple statements, enclosed in curly braces, eg: `x -> { x *= 2; return x; }`

A third special case is the one that allows you to avoid using curly braces, when invoking a `void` returning method, eg: `x -> System.out.println(x)`.

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
map.forEach(
    (k,v) -> {
        System.out.println(k);
        v.forEach(t->System.out.print(t.getDescription()))
    }
);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have a stream you can use peek().

```
map.entrySet().stream()
   .peek(System.out::println) // print the entry
   .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream())
   .map(t -> t.getDescription())
   .forEach(System.out::println); // print all the descriptions
```