# Find and modify specific element in ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, lambda

is some elegant way to find and modify some specific object in java? I have method like that:

```
public update(MyObj o) {
   for (MyObj objToModify: DATA) {
       if (objToModify.getId() == o.getId()) {
           objToModify.setName(o.getName());
           // and so on ...
       }
   }
}
```

Is possible to rewrite to lambda for example, or some other feature of Java 8? I had a lot of properties so I will prefer some option where I couldn't write manually set up all of new properties.

Comment: looks like you might be better off using a `Map<...,MyObj>` to directly access the object.

Comment: Can you give me example as answer please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in the following way, this will go over the whole stream and update elements even if there is more then one matching:

```
DATA.stream().filter(a -> a.getId() == o.getId()).forEach(a -> a.setName(o.getName()));
```

Or if you are sure that you only need to update one element:

```
DATA.stream().filter(a -> a.getId() == o.getId()).
    findAny().ifPresent(a -> a.setName(o.getName()));
```

Both solutions will throw `NullPointerException` if DATA has null elements the same as your original solution, if it's a posiibility and you want to prevent it you need to also check that `a` is not null in `filter`.

Comment: suggestion - shouldn't be restricted to `findFirst`

Comment: @nullpointer Not sure what OP wants but I integrated your suggestion in the answer.

Comment: I've update my question to correctness need, Is possible map ties properties automatically to update without manually writing setID, setName, setDate, etc ?

Comment: @DenisStephanov You need to do it somewhere, you can add a method to `MyObj`.

Comment: @Oleg I have last one question, what if I want set up more properties and not only Name? Can you edit this example please?

Comment: @DenisStephanov It's the same, just use a lambda with multiple statements https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34557412/more-then-1-command-in-the-java-8-foreach-function

Answer (score 2):

You can use lambda expression to do what you are trying to do

```
public update(MyObj o) {

    DATA.forEach(objToModify -> {

        if (objToModify.getId() == o.getId()) {
            objToModify.setName(o.getName());
            // and so on ...
        }
    });   
}
```

although i am not sure if using `lambda expression` in your case will be more efficient than using `for-each` loop.